# Get Vimeo thumbnail for video using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, thumbnails, vimeo

I've found similar questions but none of the answers show clearly and easily how to get a thumbnail for a vimeo video using jQuery and JSON. If anyone can help that would be great, here is what I've got but it shows nothing at the moment.

```
var vimeoVideoID = '17631561';
var videoCallback = 'showThumb';

$.getJSON('http://www.vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' + vimeoVideoID + '.json?callback=' + videoCallback,

function(data){
$(".thumbs").attr('src',data[0].thumbnail_large);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I agree, jQuery is really the best, it solves all kinds of browser problems and is good, as well.

Comment: I'm not the only one then :), vote the question up if you can since it might help get an answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I believe you're having the "[same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)" issue. You should consider writing a server side script using something like "[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)" or "[fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)", enabling you to grab the data from vimeo, translate it to json, and output to your javascript with a nice ajax call.

If you would like to avoid using a server-side script you may use the data type JSONP.

```
var vimeoVideoID = '17631561';

$.getJSON('https://www.vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' + vimeoVideoID + '.json?callback=?', {format: "json"}, function(data) {
         $(".thumbs").attr('src', data[0].thumbnail_large);
});
```

Notice the URL is a bit different from how you are using it. The callback which you defined as a var is unnecessary. You're attaching the getJSON to a function directly, so you'll call the 'callback' in the url '?'. This informs the getJSON function to pass the successful data return to the supplied function.

You can test my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lmcculley/M3w8p/). Hope it helps!

Comment: I wouldn't really know how to go about that and it seems excessive and unnecessary. It should be just a simple json request for the image I think but maybe your right thanks for the info anyway.

Comment: If you do not want to use a server-side script, perhaps consider using JSONP over JSON. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP
http://vimeo.com/api/docs/response-formats#jsonp

It will bypass the need for a server-side script, and enable you to do what you'd like. There are drawbacks, which is why I'm linking to the wikipedia page describing them. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok that sounds good how would I modify the code in the question to work with JSONP.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect how you would use your script with JSONP so that may mark it as answered.

Comment: I have a little problem with having multiple different vimeo videos on a single page look http://jsfiddle.net/3wFUC/ can you help? and thanks again for the answer, sorry to be a pain in the ass.

Comment: When the site is finished you will very much be getting a mention on the thanks page. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: JSONP is definitely the way to go, especially when it is already provided by API in question.

Answer (score 5):

With the [updated API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed/videos), it would be...

```
$.getJSON('https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://vimeo.com/' + id, {format: "json"}, function(data) {
  $(".thumbs").attr('src', data.thumbnail_url)
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for adding the new API version!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function which supports all types of Vimeo links & sizes:

```
function get_vimeo_thumbnail(url, size, callback)
{
    var result;
    if(result = url.match(/vimeo\.com.*[\\\/](\d+)/))
    {
        var video_id   = result.pop();
        if(size == 'small'){
            var video_link = encodeURIComponent("https://vimeo.com/" + video_id + "?width=480&height=360");
            $.getJSON('https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=' + video_link, function(data) {
                if(data && data.thumbnail_url){
                    if (typeof(callback) !== 'undefined') {
                        callback(data.thumbnail_url);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $.getJSON('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' + video_id + '.json', function(data) {
                if(data){
                    if (typeof(callback) !== 'undefined') {
                        var thumbnail_src = data[0].thumbnail_large;
                        if(thumbnail_src){
                            callback(thumbnail_src);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
// Available sizes: large, small
get_vimeo_thumbnail('https://vimeo.com/475772381', 'large' function(url){
   alert(url)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check out [this page](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed); Vimeo has a new method call `oEmbed` as Vimeo is now pushing it's new oEmbed technology.

The method above, will fail on IE (no thumbs will be shown).